# How to access parent div and closest element to that div using jquery or java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

#### HTML:

```
<h3 style="display:none;" class="relItemhide ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a href="#">Related Items</a></h3>
<div style="display: none;" class="relItemhide ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="relItemdisplay"></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If `.relItemdisplay` class text is not equal to blank, I want to change the CSS of `div` and `h3` to `display: block;`.

This is what I have tried so far but its not working

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".relItemdisplay").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() !== "") {
      $(this).parent().closest('h3').css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to navigate your way around the DOM, I recommend you use classes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".relItemdisplay").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() !== "") {
      $('relItemhide').css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

Although I'm not sure why you are using `.each()`, but I have a funny feeling you have multiple blocks of these.  If that is the case let me know, and I'll update my answer.  If not, it can be simplified to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(".relItemdisplay").text().trim() !== "") {
    $('relItemhide').css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

Updated for multiple blocks:

Html:

```
<div class="relItem">
<h3 style="display:none;" class="relItemhide ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a href="#">Related Items</a></h3>
<div style="display: none;" class="relItemhide ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="relItemdisplay"></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="relItem">
<h3 style="display:none;" class="relItemhide ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a href="#">Related Items</a></h3>
<div style="display: none;" class="relItemhide ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="relItemdisplay"></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".relItem .relItemdisplay").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() !== "") {
      $(this).parents('.relItem').find('.relItemhide').css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Should `$('relItemhide').css("display", "none");` be changed to `$('relItemhide').css("display", "block");` as OP wants?

Comment: @DennisR thanks. The original question has been modified, my code was a copy of one of the modifications (incorrect edit apparently), I'll change it to block.

Comment: Hi @ErikPhilips can you point out, why the condition is not working for him. What was the problem?